# Problem with SendMessage (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, sendmessage

I send a Message to an external program :

```
SendMessage(Handle, WM_CHAR, Ord('A'), 0);
```

But i don't know how can i receive this message in another program ? (with WndProc or something like that) may somebody explain that for me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Read [How to send and handle a custom Windows message](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/howto_send_custom_window_message.htm)

**Untested Code:**

```
const

  WM_REFRESHSOMETHING = WM_USER + 6;
```

On the Form which should catch the Message you need something like:

```
...
procedure WMRefreshsomething(var ppbMsg : TMessage); message WM_REFRESHSOMETHING;
...

procedure YourForm.WMRefreshsomething(var ppbMsg : TMessage);
begin
  //Actions...
end;
```

And then you can send a message like:

```
SendMessageToAll(Handle, WM_REFRESHSOMETHING, 0, 0);
```

To all Forms which have the message WM_REFRESHSOMETHING;

See this compilable [Example](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/de/showcode.php?id=163)

Comment: I have . but it's not clear for me . i need a practical example.

Comment: That won't help for input. Input is special.

Comment: @O.D. That's very nice and all, but it doesn't address the question which was about faking input.

Comment: Also it should be in the `WM_APP` range and you've not tackled marshalling data across the process boundary.

Comment: @David, the question that was asked was not about faking input. The question asked how to handle a message.

Comment: @Rob The message was WM_CHAR which is what you send when trying to fake input. As I'm sure you know, sometimes you have to read between the lines a little.

Comment: @Rob When I answered, all we had was `WM_CHAR`. It simply did not occur to me that anyone would choose `WM_CHAR` when they wanted `WM_COPYDATA`! Hence the fixation with input. It would seem with the comments, the fact that OP controls both apps, and the odd registry "solution", that input was a total red herring. I've deleted my answer and up-voted this one. This answer would be better if it mentioned cross-process marshalling and gave `WM_COPYDATA` as one possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code in a series of programs; one program launches programs, and when each program finishes, they send a message back to the launcher that they have finished. The key to the program is using the HWND_BROADCAST parameter: the message is sent to all running programs on the computer, but of course it is handled only by those who have the correct message handler. 
In the program which has to send the message, write

> SendMessage (HWND_BROADCAST, RegisterWindowMessage ('message'), 0, 0);

Obviously, you would replace 'message' with some string which is a constant in both programs (the one that sends and the one that receives).

I don't recommend the use of the lparam parameter of SendMessage in order to pass data to the receiving program; this is supposed to be a pointer, and of course a pointer to data in program 1 would point to garbage in program 2. One could cast a longint to a pointer and send that, which would then have to be dereferenced on the receiving side

In the receiving program,

```
type
 TWMMYMessage = record
 Msg: Cardinal;   // ( first is the message ID )
 Handle: HWND;    // ( this is the wParam, Handle of sender)
 Info: Longint;   // ( this is lParam, pointer to our data)
 Result: Longint;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 wm_Launcher:= RegisterWindowMessage ('message')  
 // wm_launcher is a private member of TForm
 .
 .
 .
end;

procedure TForm1.DefaultHandler(var Message);
var
 ee: TWMMYMessage;

begin
 with TMessage (Message) do
  begin
   if (Msg = wm_Launcher) then
    begin
     ee.Msg:= Msg;
     ee.Handle:= wParam;
     ee.Info:= lParam;
     // Checking if this message is not from us
     if ee.Handle <> Handle then WmMyMessage(ee);
    end
   else inherited DefaultHandler(Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.WmMyMessage(var Msg: TWMMYMessage);
begin
 startbtnclick (nil)   // here we actually do something when the message is received
end;
```